# Graphing a given sine function

Tags: excel, graph, trigonometry

So given is a function:

> y=A*sin(ω*t+φ)

```
Whereas A= 10V  --
w=2*pi*f && (f=1kHz)  --
t= time  --
φ=0  --
```

Can anyone explain how to do it in Excel?

Comment: Well there is the `=SIN()` and `=COS()` function in Excel, so you can just put your times in column A, and then use this function `=SIN($C$1*A1+$D$1)` and drag down. Where omega is in C1 and phi in D1. Then you select column A and B and insert a chart. (probably best to use a scatter chart with smoothed lines)

Comment: @MarcoGetrost Can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is the `=SIN()` and `=COS()` function in Excel, so you can just put your times in column A, and then use this function `=SIN($C$1*A1+$D$1)` and drag down. Where omega is in C1 and phi in D1. Then you select column A and B and insert a chart. (probably best to use a scatter chart with smoothed lines)